# Color based on distance

Tags: actionscript-3

> This question *already* has a working answer at : **[Weird graphical bug in > AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770499/2057709)**

I'm trying to make a simple tile lighting system in AS3 and the problem I've come across is that I have no idea how to change the color based on distance using hexadecimal color codes

heres the code for the color changing part:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    lightFact = getDistance(lightSource, buttons[i])
    colorTransform2.color = 0x000000
    DisplayObject(buttons[i]).transform.colorTransform = colorTransform2;
}
```

lightFact being the distance from the lightSource, if you can't figure that out from the function name.

Comment: So is your issue the color calculation or the distance calculation?  Presumably the former since your code has it hard coded in, but it would be good to make that clear.   If you want to see some code for adjusting brightness/darkness, see [this example](http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=323)  OR [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258800/how-can-i-calculate-shades-of-a-given-hex-color-in-actionscript-3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the final objective is for this code but here we go.

`getDistance()` should return a numeric value. Next step is to create a function or algorithm that codify a number into a color. This could be just setting the `R` of the `RGB` color equals to the distance (setting a cap in 255) or many `if`-`else` statements like:

```
if(lightFact < XValue)
{
    colorTransform2.color = 0xFF0000;
}
else if(lightFact < YValue) 
{
    colorTransform2.color = 0x00FF00;
}
else
{
    colorTransform2.color = 0x0000FF;
}
```

or any other more complex codification you might like. Any codification you choose will, either way, need some kind of logic that checks `lightFact`'s value and based on it (and any other variables you may have) makes a calculation or decision to set a different value to `colorTransform2.color`. Otherwise `colorTransform.color` will always be `0x000000` (black/turned off).